# r - create matrix from data frame loop

Tags: r, dataframe

I have many data frames `id.1, id.2, ... ,id.21` and in each of which I want to extract 2 data points: `id.1[5,4]` and `id.1[10,6]`, `id.2[5,4]` and `id.2[10,6]`, etc. The first data point is a date and the second data point is a integer.

I want to export this list to obtain something like this in an `.csv` file:

```
        V1          V2
1    5/10/2016      1654395291
2    5/11/2016      1645024703
3    5/12/2016      1763825219
```

I have tried

```
 x=c(for (i in 1:21) {
            file1 = paste("id.", i, "[5,4]", sep="")}, for (i in 1:21) {
            file1 = paste("id.", i, "[10,6]", sep="")})
 write.csv(x, "x.csv")
```

But this yields `x` being `NULL`. How can I go about getting this vector?

Comment: See the [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames) on working with data.frames in lists. It makes operations such as the one you are attempting much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that a `for` loop doesn't return anything in R. So you can't use it in a `c` statement as you did. Use an `[sl]apply` construct instead.

I would first make a list containing all the data frames:

```
dfs <- list(id.1, id.2, id.3, ...)
```

And iterate over it, something like:

```
x <- sapply(dfs, function(df) {
  return(c(df[5,4], df[10,6]))
})
```

Finally you need to transpose the result and convert it into a `data.frame` if you want to:

```
x <- as.data.frame(t(x))
```

Comment: Thank you. In reality, my data frames `id.1`, `id.2`, etc, go to a large number, say 1500. Is there a way to get `list(id.1, ... , id.1500)` without having to type it in?

Comment: Use the `get` function

Comment: @FlorianRichard See the link I posted in my comment to your question.

Comment: @Imo: I see. However, I am getting the names `id.1`, `id.2`, etc from the assign function because my files originally have odd names (such as 0nwn05ua.xls or 2gof3vo2.xls): `files = list.files(pattern="*.xls")`                                               `for (i in seq_along(files)) { assign(paste("id", i, sep = "."), read.xlsx(files[i],1,as.data.frame=TRUE, header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, na.strings=" ")) }` so each file is assigned an `id.[i]` name but I don't know how to retrieve this in the `list()` function.

Comment: Why do you assign them to a variable rather than saving them in a list?

Comment: `dfs <- lapply(files, function (file) {read.xlsx(file, 1, as.data.frame=TRUE, header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, na.strings=" ")})`

Comment: @FlorianRichard btw this is described in plenty of detail in this answer to the question that lmo referred to earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/333599

Comment: @Calimo Indeed. Didn't get passed the first answer. Thank you.